# Determine DeepAI sdk version

Tags: ios

I have added Deep AR SDK in my IOS application but I don't know the version of SDK.
Is there any way to check Deep AR SDK version.
I know all versions are listed in https://developer.deepar.ai/downloads link.
But would like to something like "deepArView.version" etc

Comment: how do u added the Deep AR SDK in yiur app via pods or manually

Comment: I added it manually if pod is available its good.

Comment: I got it from sample project actually there is issue. on v2.3 sdk.

Comment: can we add deep AR sdk from pod?

Comment: you can get here : https://help.deepar.ai/en/articles/4397547-changelog

Comment: Link you provided just shows the improvement on versions.
I want to know how I can add framework using pod. because if i add framework manually then there is no way to determine which version was added .